# On dropdown element click its icon disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code will replace what is shown inside `<button></button>` with selected icon from dropdown list. 
This works good, only problem is that after clicking on selected element, icon inside that element will for some reason disappear? Why does this happen? I want `<li>` to be unchanged
http://codepen.io/filaret/pen/PGJEAL

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group-btn">

    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Something 111</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> Something 2222</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $selectWrapper = $('.input-group-btn');
$selectWrapper.find(".dropdown-menu li").click(function() {

    // Get <i class="fa"></i>
    var $selectedIcon = $(this).find('.fa');
    // Put it inside <button></button>
    $selectWrapper.find(".btn").html($selectedIcon);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise since you have i tag in dropdown and button tag and that only class change, why don't you just copy the class, it's more efficient, faster and easy to understand in your code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  "use strict";

  var $selectWrapper = $('.input-group-btn');
  var $buttonIcon = $('.btn i');

  $selectWrapper.find(".dropdown-menu li").click(function() {

    // Get <i class="fa"></i>
    var $selectedIcon = $(this).find('.fa');

    // get icon classes
    var classes = $selectedIcon.attr("class");

    // Put the class in the button i tag
    $buttonIcon.attr('class', classes);

  });

});
```

See code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORxQPZ

Answer (score 3):

You need to clone the icon using `clone()` like following

```
var $selectedIcon = $(this).find('.fa').clone();
```

instead of

```
var $selectedIcon = $(this).find('.fa');
```

**[UPDATED CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALQVBq?editors=1010)**

Comment: could you explain exactly what was causing the problem? I understand that clone() makes a deep copy of the element, but unsure why the problem was there initially

Comment: Thank you, this works... but why is cloning even necessary? Finding an element doesn't delete it :/

Comment: Finding an element doesn't delete it. But when you use `append()` or `html()` it is moved from its old location. @IvanTopić